# What's the difference between np.random.standard_normal and np.random.randn?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

Both seem to draw samples from the standard normal distribution, just that standard_normal takes arguments for size and randn takes arguments for dimensions. I'm still new to this so can someone tell me if their uses will be different? Will the results they give be different?

Answer (score 0):

As documented in `randn`:

> [This is a convenience function. If you want an interface that takes a tuple as the first argument, use numpy.random.standard_normal instead.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html)

1.17 documentation is even more explicit (note `randn` has been moved in that version):

> [This is a convenience function for users porting code from Matlab, and wraps numpy.random.standard_normal.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.17.0/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.randn.html#numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.randn)